# Modal hides behind PDF on IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, pdf

I am writing an app which shows a modal on page load. I happen to have a PDF *embedded* into the html. When bootstrap modal is opened, its border and other things hide behind the PDF on Internet Explorer. It happens to work perfectly on Google Chrome.

`<embed src = "/video_library/test2.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1&statusbar=0&zoom=100" width="100%" height="590px" style="border:none;position:relative;z-index:0;"  type='application/pdf' />`

I tried applying `z-index` to `modal`, it did not work either. Plus `<object>` tag doesn't seem to have any positive effect.